# I don't mind if I do

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

What does the auxiliary verb **do** stand for in the following?

> A: “Would you like another cup of coffee?”

> B: “Thank you: I don't mind if I **do**!”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you found your example from this page on the [Merriam Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/I%20don%27t%20mind%20if%20I%20do). As you have seen there, the idiom is "used as a polite way of accepting something".

---

Person B is being asked whether they would like to have another cup of coffee.  Therefore, when Person B says: "I don't mind if I **do**," they are accepting the coffee politely and saying the equivalent of "I don't mind if I **have another cup of coffee**."

The cup of coffee has already been established as being discussed, so Person B does not have to repeat "another cup of coffee".  Person D in the example below does not need to say "I like the car." (which repeats "the car") because it is already part of the context.

> C: Do you like the car?

> D: I like it.

Comment: Does the "do" stand for "would like" in my example?

Comment: No, as the answer stated, it stands for "have another cup of coffee". _I don't mind if I would like_ doesn't make sense.